# Таймер каждой нажатой кнопки должен запускаться только после завершения предыдущего

Tags: javascript, async-await, settimeout

Всем хорошего времени суток!

Прошу помочь решить небольшую задачку.

Имеется функциональный компонент, который рендерит 3 кнопки. При нажатии на первую кнопку запускается таймер на 7 секунд и возвращается промис (назовем ее "медленной"). При нажатии на вторую кнопку происходит тоже самое, но промис возвращается через 2 секунды ("быстрая"). Третья кнопка сбрасывает состояние. Далее, в консоль передаются некоторые данные - время нажатия кнопки, количество секунд таймаута и время выведения данных в лог. По отдельности все работает хорошо.

Вопрос: как можно сделать так, что бы данные о нажатии кнопок передавались в консоль не по мере выполнения таймаута для каждого промиса, а в порядке нажатия на эти самые кнопки? Т.е. таймер следующей нажатой кнопки должен запускаться только после завершения предыдущего.

Например: я нажимаю сначала "медленную" кнопку, потом "быструю", но данные "быстрой" кнопки должны выводиться после вывода данных о "медленной" (которая была нажата первой).

Вот код https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-wozniak-wl8lq

Всем огромное спасибо!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import moment from "moment";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [infoPress, setInfoPress] = React.useState({
    time: moment().format("LTS"),
    buttonNumber: "5"
  });

  const delayAndGetRandom = info => {
    return new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve(info), info.buttonNumber * 1000)
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const printFiles = async function() {
      const press = await delayAndGetRandom(infoPress);
      return press;
    };

    printFiles().then(res =>
      console.log(moment().format("LTS"), Number(res.buttonNumber), res.time)
    );
  });

  const clearState = e => {
    setInfoPress({
      time: "не установлена",
      buttonNumber: null
    });
  };

  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    clearState();
    setInfoPress({
      ...infoPress,
      time: moment().format("LTS"),
      buttonNumber: e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("data-key").value
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button data-key="7" onClick={handleClick}>
        Медленно
      </button>
      <button data-key="2" onClick={handleClick}>
        Быстро
      </button>
      <button onClick={clearState}>Очистить</button>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот примерная концепция такая.

```js
let queue = Promise.resolve();

function delay(timeout, callback) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback(timeout);
      res();
    }, timeout)
  );
}

function onClick(e) {
  const timeout = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-delay"));

  queue = queue.then(() => delay(timeout, console.log));
}

document.querySelector('.block').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <button class="btn" data-delay="3000">3000</button>
  <button class="btn" data-delay="2000">2000</button>
  <button class="btn" data-delay="1000">1000</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! У меня была мысль попробовать сделать очередь, но мысль дальше не ушла. Попробую ваше решение.